# NSMutableDictionary ,setValue:forKey: crash

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

By chance, this code will crash:

```
-(void)addCallbackOfFileType:(SendFileType)fileType
                    callback:(sendProcess)callback
                      target:(id)target{
    
    [_hashTable addObject:target];

    NSString * targetKeyStr = NSStringFromClass([target class]);
    if (callback && targetKeyStr) {
        NSString * fid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)fileType+KBigFileAdded];
        NSMutableDictionary * targetMdic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        if ([_callbacks valueForKey:targetKeyStr]) {
            targetMdic = [_callbacks valueForKey:targetKeyStr];
        }
        [targetMdic setValue:callback forKey:fid];
        [_callbacks setValue:targetMdic forKey:targetKeyStr];
    }
    
}
```

It crashes on this line:

```
[targetMdic setValue:callback forKey:fid];
```

This is a screenshot of the crash:

[image]

How to fix this crash?

Comment: Better use `NSMutableDictionary` methods `setObject:forKey:` and `objectForKey:` instead of `NSKeyValueCoding` methods `setValue:forKey:` and `valueforKey:`.

Comment: Is `callback` an Objective-C object?

Comment: callback is a block

Comment: So you're trying to store an Objective-C block  as a value in a dictionary? That raises some memory management questions...

Comment: Not quite understand